# How do I bind this function to elements that haven't been created yet?

Tags: jquery, bind, autosize

I am trying to get this autosize function to work.
If I create the textarea before the page load it works fine:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.hellothere').autosize();  
});
```

However, if i create the textarea using jQuery later on after the page has loaded, it is not binded to this function, any help?

Comment: why can't you call autosize() after you have created the textarea?

Answer (score 2):

You can't, you will need to call `.autosize()` for each newly created textarea. If this was event binding you could `delegate()`, but you're initializing a plugin and it would need to have the actual elements to work with.

Comment: there is always a way to do it, even if it is not obvious. you should not be so fast to dismiss the possibility - is javascript not turing complete?

Comment: Well, of course. You could wait for [DOM4 `MutationObserver`](http://www.w3.org/TR/dom/#mutationobserver) to reach spec-stability and significant browser adoption (which is not likely to happen in the next 10 years), or you could build a timer to watch the results for the selector continuously and monitor them for changes (which is likely nasty on performance). Judging from the question, both solutions are not suitable for the asker, but the `livequery` answers are better than mine, although I'm betting it would also be nasty on performance.

Comment: This is now an interesting answer. Thanks. Do you expect that livequery works by running on a timer loop? I could not find the part in the source that loops, or watches for mutation of dom: https://github.com/brandonaaron/livequery/blob/master/jquery.livequery.js

Comment: Turns out liveQuery works by intercepting all jQuery methods that mutate the DOM. Won't be bad for performance, but will not notice if non-jQuery code touches the DOM.

Comment: Well that is interesting. I think you should write this all up as a full answer. I would vote for you!

Answer (score 2):

you will need to call .autosize() for each newly created textarea.

or you can use liveQuery a jquery plugin this is a great plugin and automatically apply autosize to every newly created element.

http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/livequery

Answer (score 2):

You could try [livequery](http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/livequery)

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.hellothere').livequery(function() {
       $(this).autosize();
    });  
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I think **.on()** is what you're looking for: [link](http://api.jquery.com/on/)

Attaches live event handlers to selection (whether or not they exist yet).

```
$(function(){

    // Attach a listener to all paragraphs
    $('body').on(('click', 'p', function(event){
        $(this).css('color', 'blue');
    });

    // Dynamically add a paragraph
    $('body').append('<p>Hello World!</p>');

});
```

But since you're adding the textarea with jQuery anyway, why not just invoke **.autosize()** right after you insert it?

```
$('body').append('<textarea class="hellothere"></textarea>').autosize();
```

Answer (score 0):

To bind elements which are not loaded on page yet use one of these with respect to your jQuery version.

```
 $("a.offsite").live("click", function(){ alert("Goodbye!"); }); // jQuery 1.3+
 $(document).delegate("a.offsite", "click", function(){ alert("Goodbye!"); }); // jQuery 1.4.3+
 $(document).on("click", "a.offsite", function(){ alert("Goodbye!"); }); // jQuery 1.7+
```

Referenced by:

http://api.jquery.com/live/

Answer (score -1):

Using part of an answer someone provided, then deleted, this works:

```
 $('.hellothere').live('click',function(){  $(this).autosize(); })
```